# How to update sql with Update using ExecuteSqlCommand with parameters as list

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

I have following query,

```
var sqlQuery = @Update dbo.SampleTable SET Status=@inStatuses, Dates = @inDates WHERE Id = @Ids.
```

While I already have prepared list of parameters as :

```
    var paramStatuses = deliveryInfoForUpdate.Select(pr => pr.statuses).Select(status=> new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@inStatuses", Value = status, DbType = DbType.Int32 }).ToList();

    var paramIds = deliveryInfoForUpdate.Select(pr => pr.Ids).Select(Id => new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Ids", Value = Id, DbType = DbType.Int64 } ).ToList();

    var paramDates = deliveryInfoForUpdate.Select(pr => pr.dates).Select(date=> new SqlParameter()  { ParameterName = "@inDates",  Value = date, DbType = DbType.DateTime }).ToList();
```

and I am calling ExecuteSqlCommand method in following way.

```
 DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlQuery,paramStatuses, paramDates,paramIds );
```

So, I have to update the table's 2 columns ( Status, Dates ) on the basis of passed Ids. How can I do that? At the moment I am getting following exception

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter,
>   System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native
>   type.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do several updates, do several updates. You are now trying to do something you cannot do in SQL, namely using lists as parameters and somehow expecting an update for each entry in those lists. Ask yourself what should happen if the lists are not of equal length, for instance. You have tagged your question with `entity-framework`, which raises the question why you do not use entity framework to do this...

Comment: Maybe check this out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: oerkelens : I don't want to load entire list of objects using entity framework where I have to perform an update. One single object contains 120 columns. While I only have to update 2 columns of that big Table ( i.e. SampleTable ). Therefore, it's not Ok to update using entity framework here. I believe there is a way to perform SQL Update.

Comment: you can attach the entries to the DbContext and set them to modified if you are sure there are only updates done, then not the whole object tree has to be materialized. If you want to use ExecuteSqlCommand explicitly, you'll have to build many SqlCommands, or fill one loong SqlCommand text with many update statements with the values from your list.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro : For example I have following Ids against which I have to update status, date in ""SampleTable". 

var Ids = deliveryInfoForUpdate.Select(pr => pr.Id).ToList();
Can you elaborate how can I update using entity framework with attach method.?